# Application exit on back button press

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am facing one unprecedented issue.

I am calling activity from one fragment class.
When I press back button ( toolbar back also ) it works fine and I can able to see the previous fragment.

But, the game starts now.
If I leave the application by pressing the home button, then again I come back into the application. Now If I press back button, the app closes instead of showing back fragment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is something you have done in `onCreate` but you have not done in `onResume`.

Comment: You probably finished your previous `Activity` when you are moving to next one . Double check your code . If not then add your code with question we can not make assumptions.

Comment: @ADM
I simply called the activity, and there is nothing related to finish activity in Oncreate,onResume

Comment: Maybe you have the option 'Don't keep activities' checked under developer option.

Comment: @lldix
No, It is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I have provided a Single Instance in the manifest for the activity.

Comment: This should not be necessary. That is the wrong approach. There is somethng else wrong with your implementation.